# TFS Merge historical version comes up with wrong chageset

Tags: tfs

I followed these steps:

1. Created a new development branch from our Mainline branch using a changeset from last Friday. There have been other changes checked in since then that I now don't want.
2. Made a change to the development branch.

Now, I want to overwrite the Mainline branch with the contents of the development branch, so I tried this:

```
s:\AllTfs>tf merge /recursive /force /version:T "$/Development" "$/Mainline"
```

When the merge asks me to resolve conflicts, I picked Take Source for all of them.

The resulting changeset doesn't seem to be what I want. I can't work out what it thinks it's doing, but if I look at files I expect to be rolled back and do diffs, there are no changes for them they just show up with Change types of 'merge'.

How can I achieve what I want... effectively replace Mainline with how it was on Friday with one additional change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proceeding with `/baseless` is one option for you.
Another one, which I would have picked, is to rollback all checkins that were apparently of no use at all.
With installed [TFS Power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) navigate to "File >> Source Control >> Rollback" and simply pick the range of bad checkins and roll them back:
[image]

This would spare you the trouble of constructing the branch + having to rely on the `\baseless` option to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when I added the /baseless option, I seemed to be able to get the correct changes pended.